# Django templates - how to strictly check for equality of a string

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, tabular, templatetags

I struggling to solve the following:

I am customizing django tabular inline template which contains several fields.

I have a condition

```
{% if field.field.name == 'productid' %} ... {% endif %}
```

However there are two fields that have the ... condition applied which is "productid" and "distributionid price productid" - both contain the productid word. However, I want only the former to have it. How can I make this condition more strict?

Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
html file:

```
        {% if field.field.name == 'productid' %}
                <input type="text" name="PN" id="PN" placeholder="PN:"/>
        {% endif %}
        {% if field.field.name != 'productid' %}
            <td class="field-{{ field.field.name }}"
               data-id="{{ field.field.id }}" data-type="id">

          {% if field.is_readonly %}
              <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
          {% else %}
              {{ field.field.errors.as_ul }}
              {{ field.field }}
          {% endif %}
```

(rerults in [image: result])

Comment: Can you show us your views.py file?

Comment: There is no views.py associated with this as it is the admin site (custom admin tabular inline)

Comment: I think the way you loop on field is relevant, can you share more of your html file ?

Comment: Edit added, I want to identify the field and customize it so I can trigger custom ajax request on it. I know it could be made more DRY but this is not the issue right now, it is for me so I can read it more easily :)

Comment: I'm surprised with field.field.name (instead of field.name) , can you show the for loop ? or print {{ field.field.name }} just before the if ?

Comment: it is a standart tabular inline with only litte customised part (above) it can be found yourpathtodjango\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\edit_inline\tabular.html
These are printed on the attached screenshot just before the field :)

Comment: I'am pretty sure your condition is working. But this if is not in the good scope. Your need is to have a specific input in product id column for each line ? I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if condition is outside the field td.
Just put it with field.field tag

```
                  {% if field.is_readonly or not field.field.is_hidden %}
                  <td{% if field.field.name %} class="field-{{ field.field.name }}"{% endif %}>
                  {% if field.is_readonly %}
                      <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
                  {% else %}
                      {{ field.field.errors.as_ul }}
                      {{ field.field }}
                      {% if field.field.name == 'productid' %}
                            <input type="text" name="PN" id="PN" placeholder="PN:"/>
                      {% endif %}
                  {% endif %}
                  </td>
                  {% endif %}
```